# How to iterate over an array of arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have an array of arrays that contains details of three tests. This is the array:

```
test_arr = [
  [‘unit test 1’, ‘physics’, ‘25’],
  [‘unit test 2’, ‘chemistry’, ‘30’],
  [‘final test’, ‘math’, ‘50’]
]
```

I want to iterate over this array three times (because there are only three tests whose data is contained in the array) to get a hash in an array containing only the subject and marks.

I do the iteration as follows:

```
test_arr.each do |ta|
  all_test_details << { subject: ta[1], marks: ta[2] }
end
```

I want `all_test_details` to read like this =>

```
[ { subject: ‘physics’, marks: 25 },
  { subject: ‘chemistry’, marks: 30 },
  { subject: ‘math’, marks: 50 } ]
```

But when I run the code, what I get is `all_test_details` repeated ten times. I’m unable to figure out why.

How do I get the names and marks of the test in a single array containing a hash?

Comment: Where and how is `all_test_details` defined? It should be empty initially, but it's probably not here.

Comment: can you put this line: `p test_arr` line before iteration? To make sure that there is really 3 elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of `map`:

```
test_arr.map { |data| { subject: data[1], marks: data[2] } }

#=> [{:subject=>"physics",   :marks=>"25"},
#=>  {:subject=>"chemistry", :marks=>"30"},
#=>  {:subject=>"math",      :marks=>"50"}]
```

Comment: ...And to elaborate slightly, the mistake that @liquorishe had almost certainly made was to define `all_test_details = []` at some point, and then keep **mutating** this array with `<<` - which is why this duplication was happening, since you were re-adding the values over and over to the array.

Comment: yes, that might be the reason if he ran the piece of code more than once

Comment: Thank you, Deepak. That's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @TomLord Yes, that's what I did. Seems like I keep making this mistake and when you explained it like that something sparked somewhere and immediately died. Why exactly is this a mistake? I'm still not able to completely understand the nuance. I would be grateful if you could point me to some place where I can read about how arrays are mutated.

Comment: @liquorishe The short answer is: the shovel operator (`<<`) and [any method ending in `!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) (with a few [exceptions](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-delete)) will mutate the original object. This applies to other core classes, such as `String`, too. This is a very broad topic to explain in brief, so my answer is far from complete. However, it's a very common "mistake" for beginners to use `each` in conjunction with `<<`, when they could just be using `map` instead.